# DividerItemDecoration - remove last divider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What's the right way to remove the last divider with recyclerview?

if you do it with `dividerItemDecoration` it seems awkward, I thought it was built in but it isn't if you do it with view in `row_whatever.xml` it is awkward.

Comment: Try with android:footerDividersEnabled="false" if this is not working put android:layout_height="wrap_content" as height of the recyclerview

Comment: @Merian  android:footerDividersEnabled="false"  is for listviews not recyclerciew.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView remove divider / decorator after the last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215810/recyclerview-remove-divider-decorator-after-the-last-item)

Comment: this is one of the little things flutter gets right, having a listview.separated() built in..

Answer (score 0):

Use [MaterialDividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/divider/MaterialDividerItemDecoration) and set `isLastItemDecorated` to `false`