# How to set ItemDecoration only for certain ViewType?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I want to draw a default `ItemDecoration` only for `Header Type` into `RecycleView`. But `divider` is shown for each `ViewType`.

**Custom decoration:**

```
class DividerDecoration(context: Context, orientation: Int)
    : DividerItemDecoration(context, orientation){

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        val viewType = parent.adapter!!.getItemViewType(position)
        if (viewType == ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER){
            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        } else {
            outRect.setEmpty()
        }
    }
}
```

**Set:**

```
val itemDecoration = DividerDecoration(binding.recyclerView.context, 
                                       DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
```

Any suggestions to why does this happen?

**UPDATE**

The code above is work. But with a bug. After starting the application, the divider appears in all elements, and then only the right ones. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: I don't know Kotlin(I use Java), but I don't think you can set the divider for the first item only.

Comment: @GauravMall I have `header` for each group by date

Comment: Oh okay I see, will see If I can help!

Comment: Did you try inside `getItemOffsets` to use `parent.adapter.getItemViewType(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view))`? This maybe works - haven't tried myself.

Comment: @GauravMall you certainly can.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini What do you mean?

Comment: @GauravMall " but I don't think you can set the divider for the first item only" -> you can set the divider for any row you want, but the logic to do so, is not straightforward.

Comment: I was talking about his implementation, it's not possible with his code to set only to the first item. That's how I had understood the question.

Comment: And I'm telling you it *is possible*. If his code worked, it's just a matter of not setting the divider if the position is not 0 (which would be, technically, the 1st item). It's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

My mistake consists of the conviction to use `ItemDecoration` in order to set custom dividers for different `ViewType`. I have developed a clear belief that such a custom dividers should do only `ItemDecoration`.

According `image gif` from my question, it's gives a bug. I couldn't find a solution. The other posts on `StackOverflow` is offering to `override` the methods: `getItemOffsets()` and `onDraw()`. I tried to implement at least four case. And they all ended up with a drawing bug (similar to gif from my question).

## Search

I don't know what causes these drawing errors. Thanks to [Tenfour04's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383027/5894542) answer and comments. I changed my keywords for searching and found simple solution.

By the way, the design of my application adopts some features of the design of applications from `Google`. I decompiled the apk of one of those apps. And found the resources that make the separator exactly as described in the solution. In this regard, I can consider this decision the `best practices from Google`.

### Solution

I have two `ViewType`. Each with its own layout. The solution is to add a separator to the header layout.

Because the `ViewTypeHeader` only appears if there are nested elements, in my case I don't need to add conditions with `Visible` for the last or first element.

**layout\ViewTypeHeader.xml**

```
<LinearLayout ...>

    <TextView ... />

    <!-- This -->
    <View style="@style/DividerStyle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="DividerStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/dividerHeight</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

## Conclusion

If there are several `ViewType` - forget about `ItemDecoration`. Save a lot of time.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can show or hide divider based on view type or position. Include it in your activity/fragment.

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, linearLayoutManager.getOrientation()) {
            @Override
            public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                Drawable d = getDrawable();
                for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
                    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                    int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);
                    
                    // Draw divider only for view type 2 (can also put position here to remove for certain positions)
                    if(viewType == 2) {
                        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        int top = view.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
                        int bottom = top + d.getIntrinsicHeight();
                        d.setBounds(0, top, parent.getRight(), bottom);
                        d.draw(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, trying to do this from within the Decoration implementation is messy. Now the decoration has to know about the data set, so you've got a view directly accessing the adapter to access the data. And you're determining which positions are headers in multiple different classes. Spaghetti and repetition.

Ideally, the adapter class would be handling the application of Decorations so you could do it selectively, but since it doesn't, I think the best way to do it for the time being is to put the divider in your header layout, and in `onBindView` you can turn off its visibility if the position is 0 (the topmost header).

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I'm beginner.

Comment: Which part do you need clarification about, first or second paragraph?

Comment: Examples from the Internet of creating ItemDecoration always have an implementation and somewhere else a call to the add method. Why do I choose headlines in different classes? Method getItemOffsets looks at existing type and decides whether he needs the divider. As I understand it,  do not recommend doing the divider out ItemDecoration. But if do, how to draw a line in the layout? Do you see update post?

Comment: It's just poor architecture for a view object to be deciding which other views it should be combined with. Internet examples where ItemDecorations are made to do this are a hack. getItemOffsets is supposed to return the item offsets. It is a hack to return invalid offsets or place them where it will still draw them but you just can't see them. In my opinion, since we can simply use the existing Adapter methods as they are intended to achieve the correct result, that is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Are you already inflating a layout for your header view in your Adapter?

Comment: The adapter now calls one of the two Viewholders. Title and content. The header layout is so far only a TextView. On GIF in post, red color for visibility bug. The code is the same as in the post. Only the setDrawable method is called to set the red color.

Comment: So instead of TextView, you can use a FrameLayout that has both a TextView and a plain View. You can set the background of the View to use your Drawable. It looks like you want it to be an underline, so you can set this view's layout gravity to bottom and set its layout width to `match_parent`. It's layout height is however thick you want the line to be.

Comment: In my case, I use an "overline", not an underline, so I hide the divider on the top-most header. I do this in `onBindView` in the adapter right where you set the text for the header. You can set the `visibility` parameter of the divider View to `View.VISIBLE` or `VIEW.GONE`. What I do is in the Adapter's `onBindView` when it is setting the

Answer (score -1):

Override your item decoration's `onDraw` and only perform the draw when the item 
being decorated is in a position you consider ok.

Instead of creating another example, I'll just point you to a working sample that doesn't do *exactly* what you want, but should certainly point you in the right direction: how to selectively draw dividers.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216274/2684