# Remove last item decoration from recyclerView gridlayout manager

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, divider

I have a `recyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` i want to remove last **divider** in **vertical** and **horizontal** mode.

[image]

I tried to set **empty** to last position in `outRect` but it does not work for me.

```
outRect.setEmpty()
```

I have an `extension` `fun` like this :

```
fun RecyclerView.addItemDecorationWithoutLastDivider(orientation:Int) {

    addItemDecoration(object :
        DividerItemDecoration(context,orientation) {

        override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == state.itemCount - 1)
                outRect.setEmpty()
            else
                super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        }
    })
}
```

**I set up `recyclerView` here :**

```
recyclerView.apply {
    adapter = mBankListAdapter
    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(),3,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)

    addItemDecorationWithoutLastDivider(DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
    addItemDecorationWithoutLastDivider(DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL)

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215810/recyclerview-remove-divider-decorator-after-the-last-item